# Always display shippingcost in cart

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address, shipment

We only use flat rate shipping and I always want to display the shippingcost.
Is there a way to always load the /tax/checkout/shipping.phtml file into the cart?

We use always the same shipping costs to all adresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial http://www.danneh.org/2010/08/adding-shipping-costs-to-the-cart-automatically-in-magento/

Good luck !